# show copied file in git log / git show

Tags: git

I got the following output after committing my changes:

```
[master 1d8c20c] Refactor config BCs
 5 files changed, 130 insertions(+), 424 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 kustomize/templates/build-config.yml
 rewrite kustomize/templates/build.yml (78%)
 copy kustomize/templates/{build.yml => common-build.yml} (61%)
```

But if I now use `git log` or `git show` it does not show the copy/rewrite part, how do I get git to display it in `git log` or `git show`?

Tried so far:

1. Simple `git log` -- only commit message, no file status
2. `git log --summary` / `git show --summary` -- shows copy/rewrite as create

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `--summary` option to `git log` causes `git log` to run `git diff --summary` at the end.  This is also what `git commit` does for this case, so that's why you want the `--summary`.  But: `git diff`, *by default*, does not look for *copies* of files.  To make `git diff` look to see if, perhaps, a file might have been *copied* to make a new one, you must pass the `-C` flag (optionally, more than once or with `--find-copies-harder`).

The `--summary` diff that `git commit` runs includes the `-C` option by default, at least in your particular version of Git (this has changed over time so different Git versions behave slightly differently here).<sup>1</sup>  Hence, to get `git log --summary` or `git show --summary` the same way that your `git commit` showed it, add `-C` to your command's options.

Note that, as this implies, the output of `git diff` *changes* based on which options you provide.  Git didn't *store* the changes!  Git *stored* the old versions of all of your files in the old commit, and then stored the new versions of all of your files in the new commit.  (This is how Git can produce, on demand, all the files from *any* historical commit.)  The comparison commands—`git log -p`, `git log --summary`, `git show`, `git diff`, and so on—extract the two commits' snapshots and then compare them.  The comparison is done *right then*, using whatever additional options you choose *right then*, and those options affect the visible result, which is only computed right when you ask for it.  All Git *really* has is the stored snapshots (plus some metadata) in each commit.

---

<sup>1</sup>You can also change some defaults with certain `git config` settings.  For instance, `git config --global diff.renames true` enables rename detection, even in older versions of Git (pre-Git-2.9) where it is disabled by default.  You can enable copy detection by default by setting `diff.renames` to `copy`, if you like.

Comment: Thank you. :) I was quite sure i tried `git show -C --summary`, but seems like I did not. ^^ With `diff.renames copy` `git show/log --name-status` now also shows the similarity (e.g. `C061`), that's quite nice.